# Trying to run Tasklist in Powershell & having problems with multiple IP's / Output

Tags: powershell

I've had several iterations of this, but I can't seem to get it give me output or even close the loop.
I'm new at this, it's probably simple for even an intermediate level person...but I'm losing my mind here.

HERE'S THE SCRIPT

```
$i =124

$Ip = "166.112.76."

$Ip4th = $Ip + $i

echo $TASKLIST = Start "c:\windows\system32\tasklist.exe /s $ip4th /v /FI 'IMAGENAME eq 

caffeine.exe' >>c:\caffeine\results.txt"

echo    Do {{$TASKLIST; $i++}

echo     While ($IP4th -le "166.112.76.128")}


AND HERE'S WHAT POWERSHELL GIVES BACK...NO OUTPUT FILE CREATED EITHER


PS C:\Users\jwalke22\Documents> C:\caffeine\caff4.ps1

=
Start

c:\windows\system32\tasklist.exe /s 166.112.76.124 /v /FI 'IMAGENAME eq caffeine.exe' 

>>c:\caffeine\results.txt

Do

{$TASKLIST; $i++}

echo     While ($IP4th -le "166.112.76.128")
```

Comment: What, exactly, is the error you're getting?

Answer (score 1):

It appears you're trying to get a list of running processes on a remote machine? If so, you want:
Get-Process [[-Name] ] [-ComputerName ]

As in:

```
for ($i = 0; $i -le 255; $i++) {
    $server = "166.112.76.$i"
    Get-Process -ComputerName $server
}
```

You'll find PowerShell does a lot of these type of admin processes straight out of the box. Your intended solution failed because you did not "receive" the output of the tasklist window you created. You could do so in a couple ways, but they're all a bit technical. Easier to become familiar with the things PowerShell does for you already.

Comment: You mean looping across your servers by IP?